# Firebase permission denied randomly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I had my security rules set up and everything was working fine yesterday. I've changed nothing since but today I keep getting "Permission denied" when I try to run this transaction on "styles/$styleId/likeInfo":

```
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /styles/46/likeInfo
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /styles/46/likeInfo {likeCount=0, filters={1=medium_casual_male/46, 0=all_casual_male/46}, likeModified=0}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44997
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={b={s=ok, d={}}, r=9}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {b={s=ok, d={}}, r=9}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44998
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={b={s=datastale, d=Transaction hash does not match}, r=10}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {b={s=datastale, d=Transaction hash does not match}, r=10}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - p response: {s=datastale, d=Transaction hash does not match}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25355/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/EventRaiser: Raising /styles/46/likeInfo: VALUE: {likeCount=1, likeModified=1474732236378, filters={1=medium_casual_male/46, 0=all_casual_male/46}}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={b={h=ngNr+btv0R3q08ZQFhaa7gdToL4=, d={likeCount=1, likeModified={.sv=timestamp}, filters={1=medium_casual_male/46, 0=all_casual_male/46}}, p=styles/46/likeInfo}, r=11, a=p}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:36.491 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44996
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25424/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":11,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Permission denied"}}}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44711
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={b={s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}, r=11}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {b={s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}, r=11}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - p response: {s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug W/RepoOperation: Transaction at /styles/46/likeInfo failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25355/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/EventRaiser: Raising /styles/46/likeInfo: VALUE: {likeCount=0, likeModified=0, filters={1=medium_casual_male/46, 0=all_casual_male/46}}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - unlistening on styles/46/likeInfo (params: {})
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - removing query styles/46/likeInfo (params: {})
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={b={p=styles/46/likeInfo}, r=12, a=n}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44997
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25355/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/SwipeListener: User: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafu@a507f090
09-24 11:50:36.781 25355-25355/in.nyuyu.android.debug E/SwipeListener: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
                                                                       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown)
                                                                           at in.nyuyu.android.commons.Rx$4.onComplete(Rx.java:88)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahq$11.run(Unknown)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 11:50:37.021 25355-25424/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":12,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
09-24 11:50:37.021 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44762
09-24 11:50:37.021 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
09-24 11:50:37.021 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={b={s=ok, d=}, r=12}, t=d}
09-24 11:50:37.021 25355-25379/in.nyuyu.android.debug D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {b={s=ok, d=}, r=12}
```

My security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "sessions":{
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "styles":{
      "$styleid":{
        "likeInfo": {
        ".write": "auth!= null",
            "filters":{
              ".validate": "newData.val() == data.val()"
            },
            "likeCount": {
              ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == data.val()+1"
            },
            "likeModified": {
              ".validate": "newData.val() == now"
            }
        }
      }
    },
    "stylefilters":{
      "$filterCombo":{
        "$styleId":{
          "likeCount": {
                ".write": "auth!= null",
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() > data.val()"
            },
            "likeModified":{
                ".write": "auth!= null",
              ".validate": "newData.val() > data.val()"
                }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I know the user is authenticated as I'm printing the user object: `D/SwipeListener: User: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafu@a507f090` and the data being sent seems to fit the validation rules I've specified.

My firebase version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
```

Update:

This is the java code running the transaction:

```
public class LikeCountTransaction {

    public static final String PATH = "styles/%s/likeInfo";
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Inject public LikeCountTransaction(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        this.databaseReference = databaseReference;
    }

    public Observable<DataSnapshot> execute(Long styleId) {
        String path = String.format(PATH, styleId);
        Timber.d("Transaction path: %s", path);
        return Rx.transact(databaseReference.child(path), mutableData -> {
            MutableData likeCount = mutableData.child("likeCount");
            Long likeCountValue = likeCount.getValue(Long.class);
            if (likeCountValue != null) {
                likeCount.setValue(likeCountValue + 1);
                mutableData.child("likeModified").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }).toObservable();
    }
}
```

This is where the PermissionDenied Error is thrown:

```
public static Single<DataSnapshot> transact(DatabaseReference databaseReference, TransactionExecutor handler) {
        return Observable.<DataSnapshot>fromEmitter(emitter -> databaseReference.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                return handler.execute(mutableData);
            }

            @Override public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (committed) {
                    emitter.onNext(dataSnapshot);
                    emitter.onCompleted();
                } else {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        emitter.onError(databaseError.toException()); <------------------ Permission Denied Error
                    } else {
                        emitter.onError(new Throwable("Transaction did not commit"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }), AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.LATEST).toSingle();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the minimal code that triggers the error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated the post

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It seems like the rule on "filters" is stopping the transaction, `".validate": "newData.val() == data.val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the validation rule on my "filters" to

```
"filters":{
    "$filterIndex": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() == data.val()"
        }
    }
```

I guess the rules don't evaluate two arrays to be equal even if they have the same data.

Comment: That last statement is indeed correct: comparisons in security rules are shallow (as they are in JavaScript). Note that it is very hard for us to spot such a mistake without seeing as minimal sample of the JSON too. In general when you have a problem, reproduce that problem in isolation (so outside of your app) and use that in your question. Such a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for Firebase would include the JSON (as text), the rules and the code. Having this makes it a lot easier to see the  problem.